# Are there other examples of human-electric hybrid aircraft?

Tags: electric-engine, amateur-experimental

Has there been a human-electric hybrid aircraft after this. A more streamlined design; maybe capable of soaring as well...

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by human-electric? it seems more electric than human powered... anyway the descendant of the Gossamer Penguin has been the [Solar Challenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCready_Solar_Challenger), another solar powered aicraft. The predecessor of the Penguin was a human-powered aircraft, the [Gossamer Albatross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacCready_Gossamer_Albatross). [Aaalbaatrooossss...!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_u7VGiMO0U)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I assume by hybrid you mean that propulsion is provided by a solar-powered electric motor while the control system is powered by a human pilot.

From Paul McCready came Solar Challenger in 1981, certainly less flimsy than the Gossamer Penguin.

[image: Solar Challenger]

Solar Challenger (picture [source](http://www.airwar.ru/image/idop/xplane/solarchallenger/solarchallenger-3.jpg))

In the same year, [Solair I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solair) flew for the first time, followed by [Solair II](http://www.solair.de) in 1998. Both were built by Günther Rochelt, who also built human powered aircraft.

[image: Solair II]

Solair II (picture [source](http://www.buch-der-synergie.de/c_neu_html/c_fotos_ok/elektromobile/909_solarflugzeug_solair_2_1.jpg))

Rochelt's Musculair 2, the fastest human powered aircraft until today, inspired Eric Raymond to build Sunseeker in 1990. Sunseeker II improved on those designs again, still using the layout pioneered by Musculair 2. It flew first in 2002.

[image: Sunseeker]

Sunseeker (picture [source](http://images.thecarconnection.com/lrg/sunseeker-solar-glider-image-solar-flight_100420707_l.jpg))

[Icaré 2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icar%C3%A9_II) was based on glider technology and flew first in 1996.

[image: Icaré 2]

Icaré 2 (picture by Uli Reinhardt, Zeitenspiegel (Zeitenspiegel) [[CC BY-SA 2.0 de](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/de/deed.en), [GFDL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html) or [CC-BY-SA-3.0]](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), via Wikimedia Commons

With [Sunseeker Duo](http://www.solar-flight.com/projects/sunseeker-duo/) the first solar-powered two seater flew in 2014.

For a comprehensive history of solar flight see [here](https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/mavt/robotics-n-intelligent-systems/asl-dam/documents/projects/History_of_Solar_Flight_Skysailor.pdf) (PDF), and for some more background see [here](http://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/ewade/2009/EWADE2009_Ross.pdf).